# reCaptcha appearing at the top of my form even though I've put it at the bottom in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, recaptcha

Using the [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) package to use reCaptcha in my [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) signup form (doesn't really matter, I was having the same problem without the package).

So I simply place the reCaptcha (`{{ form.captcha }}`) after my form inputs (but before the submit input):

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {{ form.captcha }}
  {{ form.captcha.errors }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

`form.as_p` is the form inputs.

However, this is how it renders on the page:

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="/accounts/signup/">
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='nnq5OVApZrOs00ryvyPpVZYVHPKveyZzIQrP7E9PjBdFOHo4kfhEqBzGWg0ug' />
  <p><label for="id_captcha">Captcha:</label> <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="l0eIxAcTAAXXAJcZVRqyHxc1UMIEGNQ_23jiZKhI" data-theme="clean" data-id="id_captcha" data-required="True" ></div>
<noscript>
  <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px;">
    <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: relative;">
      <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: absolute;">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=l0eIxAcTAAXXAJcZVRqyHxc1UMIEGNQ_23jiZKhI"
                frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                style="width: 302px; height:352px; border-style: none;">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 250px; height: 80px; position: absolute; border-style: none;
                  bottom: 21px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px;">
        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"
                  class="recaptcha_challenge_field"
                  style="width: 250px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
                         margin: 0px; padding: 0px; resize: none;" value="">
        </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</noscript></p>
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus" required maxlength="150" id="id_username" minlength="1" /></p>
<p><label for="id_email">E-mail (optional):</label> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address" id="id_email" /></p>
<p><label for="id_password1">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password" id="id_password1" required /></p>
<p><label for="id_password2">Password (again):</label> <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Password (again)" id="id_password2" required /></p>

  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

as you can see the reCaptcha is at the top of the form. The only way I could get it to the bottom is via `position:absolute` and a ridiculous `top: 150px;` but that isn't dynamic and sustainable so I'm wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: What does your `models.py`and `forms.py` look like?